# Acessar List<List<string>> em uma Thread

Tags: c#, thread

Estou usando WinForms
Não consigo acessar uma list dentro de uma `Thread`.

Essa lista eu já populei ela através de outro método.

Se deixar o cursor em cima consigo ver os itens, porém quando vou recuperar através `lstPublicacoes[0].ToString();` só consigo visualizar o seguinte conteudo. `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`

Edit: Trecho do código.

```
List<List<string>> lstPublicacoes = new List<List<string>>();
 string TextoPublicacao="";

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    if (lstPublicacoes[i].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        TextoPublicacao = lstPublicacoes[i].;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Você pode incluir o código onde você está tendo esse problema?

Comment: @ carlosfigueira editei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você teria o mesmo comportamento se você estivesse acessando a lista tanto do mesmo thread como em threads diferentes de onde ela foi criada. O seu problema é que você está chamando o método `ToString` em um objeto da classe `List<string>`, e ele usa a implementação *default* desse método, retornando o nome da classe. Note que como você tem uma lista *de listas* de strings, um elemento da sua `List<List<string>>` é uma lista de strings, e chamar o método `ToString` não é a melhor forma para saber se a lista está vazia.

Uma opção que você pode usar é a propriedade `Count` da lista; se ela for diferente de zero, então a lista não está vazia. Note que se você quiser converter a lista de strings em uma única string (e.g., a sua variável `TextoPublicacao`), você terá que de alguma forma "juntar" as strings da sua lista. O código abaixo usa o `string.Join` para fazer isso, mas pode ser que você precise usar uma outra lógica para tal.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<string>> lstPublicacoes = new List<List<string>>();
        lstPublicacoes.Add(new List<string> { "um", "dois", "tres" });
        lstPublicacoes.Add(new List<string> { "onze", "doze", "treze" });
        lstPublicacoes.Add(new List<string> { });
        lstPublicacoes.Add(new List<string> { "vinte e um", "vinte e dois", "vinte e tres" });

        for (int i = 0; i < lstPublicacoes.Count; i++)
        {
            // Imprime System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]
            Console.WriteLine(lstPublicacoes[i].ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lstPublicacoes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lstPublicacoes[i].Count != 0)
            {
                string texto = string.Join(", ", lstPublicacoes[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(texto);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Carlos, perfeita explicação e perfeita solução. Resolvido! Obrigado!!